# How to create dependent fields in Entity:baseFieldDefinition?

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a select list of content types in baseFieldDefinition

```
$fields['ctype'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
      ->setLabel(t('Content Type'))
      ->setDescription(t('Choose content type '))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSettings(array(
        'allowed_values' => $ctypes,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -5,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_select',
        'weight' => -5,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Does Drupal provides `ajax` feature to use in `baseFieldDefinition` ?

Basically I want to generate **field list** of *selected content type* using entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Drupal provides `ajax` feature to use in `baseFieldDefinition` ?

Short answer: no

Long answer:

The base field definition method is used to define the entity structure and the database structure.

If you are trying to display different form items when the toe changes then you should do that on the **form object** level. By adding a `#ajax` attribute to the type field.

Comment: can you give any example link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right place for my answer. I´ve also defined a entity with a basefielddefinition and would like to add a ajax handler to a select list.
So i´m using the buildForm-function and add the following ajax snippet to the form:

```
$form['formid']['#ajax'] =[
'callback' => '::ajaxHandler',
'event' => 'change',
'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
'progress' => [
  'type' => 'throbber',
  'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
],

 ];
```

By using the ajax example form in my buildForm everything works fine, but not with my formid-field.
thanks for helping me.
best regards
andy

Comment: The solution is, to add the ajax handler at this position: $form['formid']['widget']['#ajax']